# Get all documents in a CouchDB database *except* the design documents

Tags: database, couchdb

In couchDB I have a database with some documents. When I create a view, the view is created inside of this database, together with the documents. Then when I take all the elements of the database, couchDB returns me all the elements including the views. Is there any way to get everything apart from the views?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
/<mydb>/_all_docs?descending=true&endkey="_design0"
```

The '0' in _design0 makes sure that the output is stopped before the first design document. The optional parameter inclusive_end=false may work as well but did not for me in a short test.

See http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/bulk-api.html for further details.

But I'd also prefer a simple view for that task.

Comment: I tried, but this skips the documents with keys bigger than "_".

Answer (score 1):

Using this should work:

```
/<mydb>/_all_docs?endkey="_design"
```

If you use only the auto-generated IDs, then you probably can also use:

```
/<mydb>/_all_docs?endkey="_"
```

but that may cause issues if you use custom IDs since the "_" character falls between uppercase and lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to 'categorize' the documents when you insert them into the CouchDB. A common technique to do this is adding a 'type' property to all the documents you created.

e.g.

```
{
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName:  'Doe',
  type: 'user'
}
```

Then you can create a [view](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views) that returns only documents with that property.

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type) {
    emit(doc._id, doc);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it without creating an extra view?